# Name of famous noodle shop in Konoha village?

Tags: naruto

You probably already know Naruto Uzumaki's favorite food is ramen, but did you know that his favorite place to enjoy his favorite meal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is named [Ichiraku Ramen](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ramen_Ichiraku):

> Ramen Ichiraku is Naruto Uzumaki's favourite dining establishment. He
> eats there regularly – usually stopping by between missions – and he
> is often joined by Iruka Umino, another frequent customer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I voted for your detailed answer.